# Relational mapping of files and entities in the database

Tags: file, filesystems, relational-database

i'm working on a new project and looking into a good approach/ Best practise for file storage and how to efficiently map the files to several resources in a relational data model.

Note: All files are uploaded on a filesystem (not a database)

**Option 1**

Creating a Files table to store meta data of each file and create a relation with each resource (e.g. user_files, product_files, ... )

Questions: Will all files be stored in a single table? If I want to fetch the user avatar I have to search in a table that also contains product images or pdf documents?

**Option 2**

Store the needed file meta data with each resource.

Downside: each resource can only have 1 image. (good for user avatar?)

**Option 3**

Files are created using a hash of the resource (e.g. user_1243_avatar)
No relation will be stored and the url will be build when the resource is fetched.

Are there other options to consider?

all input is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you store files in the filesystem. I used option 1 in a recent project and would recommend it.

> If I want to fetch the user avatar I have to search in a table that also contains product images or pdf documents?

You make it sound as if you'll have to do a table scan. In my DB, a user's avatar was indicated by an `avatar_file_id` in the `users` table, so I could join from `users` to `files` directly using an index.

Your `user_files` sounds too generic. Users could have different files for different purposes, are you just going to lump them all together? Would you create a table `person_to_person` to lump together friends, marriages, manager/employee, parent/child, etc? I wouldn't.

Create different tables for different purposes, e.g. a one-to-one table `user_avatar` (or denormalize it into your `users` table). Some more examples might be `product_images`, `product_specs`, `product_helpfiles`, etc.